# Low resultion bathymetric and elevation data (eg ~ 20' by 20`)

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am looking for a low resulution data set (grid) of the world that contains the elevation above or depth below sea level, respectively. For my purposes, it's enough if I can display the entire data set on a laptop screen. For example, with a 20 by 20 minute grid, that would be 1080x270 pixels. It could by slightly larger, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ETOPO dataset](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/) by NOAA NCEI.  It has a 1' resolution, which you can of course downsample according to your needs.

Several derived data sets are available as well.

Comment: In case someone is interested, I was able to downsample the data with `grdsample ETOPO1_Bed_g_gmt4.grd -I0.30  -G0.30.grd` to a 1200 pixel wide "image".